# Changing ip Address Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, ip

how can I change my ip address on a mac, but without proxies? I've used vpns and have gone to the advanced setting proxy list (using hidemyass etc), but I want a legitimately changed IP address. I've heard terminal can be used, but I don't know how to use that.

Answer (score 1):

An IP address is something your ISP provides your router with. It is not something you can choose.

What you can do is use a VPN to send all your traffic to some server, which then works as a relay.

(And if you're just looking to browse the web anonymously, theres always [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/))